# How do you build a model that predicts the total and the total by product so they add up for each client?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models

Imagine you can buy only 3 distinct products (A, B, C) in a store, so that:

$Y_{T} = Y_{A} + Y_{B} + Y_{C}$

I need to predict the **total** and the **total by product** for each client, **but I need the estimates to add up**:

$\hat{Y}_{T} = \hat{Y}_{A} + \hat{Y}_{B} + \hat{Y}_{C}$

I have historical transactional and demographic data, so I can build different features for the total and for each family that each client buys.

How do you approach this problem with Machine Learning?

Comment: You can simply predict the per-product estimates and them add them up to produce the total.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that be for the total a sum of all errors? If I had too a model for the total that minimize that error, what could you do?

Comment: Well, another approach would be to predict the total and also predict the percentages of each product in the total. Then, you would just multiply the percentages with the total to get the per-product estimates. Of course, you can do both approaches and combine them as an ensemble (simplest case is to take the average).

Comment: I also had the idea about predicting the percentages, do you know any library where I can putt the constraint that they add up to 1 ?

Comment: I don't know any ML algorithm that will accept specific constraints. One way is to predict the percentages and then normalize them (so they sum up to 1). The other way would be to use an NN and pass the outputs through a softmax function.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the model for the total developed and working with good results, then I would develop two other models for the easier to predict variables (w.l.o.g. A & B ) and then obtain the estimate for C by difference.

Comment: Where did you get the idea from the OP that the total for C is harder to to estimate than A and B.

Comment: What do you mean by OP? What I wanted to say is that I can see how the separate models perform, and choose the two with the highest accuracy.

Comment: The OP is a common term used on Cross Validated for the person asking the question.